# MySQL workflow with vagrant and git at different environments (sync)

Tags: php, mysql, git, vagrant, puppet

I currently try to improve my workflow with the new de facto standard software like vagrant.

My setting for a PHP / MySQL project looks like this:

- no team, just 1 dev; but working from 3 different machines (iMac, MacBook, Win 8.1 PC)
- private Github repository (dev and master branch)
- https://puphpet.com/ created vagrant box with Nginx, MySQL and PHP 5.4
- rootserver for the production files and database (pull from master-branch)

Everything works fine, but I'm not sure how I could manage the different MySQL databases. Should I add a blanko database to the production server which I only use for schema updates? If so, I could sync each schema's via Navicat or similiar applications...

Are there any best practices for the mysql part?

Comment: I'm working in a similar set-up and I put my databases under version control with http://dbv.vizuina.com
This way you can keep all your dev environments in sync with each other. Plus every database alteration is now secured in the versioning tool so you can easily revert or look back why you did that change